# Вопрос про spring context и их различие при работе с памятью

Tags: spring

Вот выдержка из доки

> "Because the ApplicationContext includes all functionality of the
>   BeanFactory, it is generally recommended over the BeanFactory, except
>   for a few situations such as in embedded applications running on
>   resource-constrained devices where memory consumption might be
>   critical and a few extra kilobytes might make a difference."

К сожалению для меня не очевиден этот момент. Не мог бы кто-то пояснить момент с памятью?

Answer (score 1):

Ну написано, что надо брать ApplicationContext и работать с ним, т.к. он обладает всем функционалом BeanFactory. За исключением приложений, которые выполняются в среде где размер памяти сильно ограничен (встроенные системы, например) и несколько лишних килобайт в памяти могут сыграть свою роль. Т.е. если память не проблема, работаем через ApplicationContext, иначе работаем через BeanFactory, т.к. она меньше места в памяти будет занимать.